# Boton Like/Unlike Django

Tags: python, django, botón

Hola estoy intentando agregarle funcionalidad de boton Like/Unlike a mi ecommerce personal con django. Estoy siguiendo este tutorial
---> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orTvLAysEHQ&list=PLgjw1dR712joFJvX_WKIuglbR1SNCeno1&index=7

Mi problema reside en que no muestra el boton like en la pagina detalle del producto. La verdad no se que hice mal porque segui tal cual explicaba el tutorial.

Store --> models.py:

```
LIKE_CHOICES = (
('Like', 'Like'),
('Unlike', 'Unlike'),)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description1 = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    description2 = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    description3 = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/products")
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ## LIKE MODEL PRODUCT ##
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name='likes')
def num_likes(self):
    return self.liked.all().count()
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created_date',)
def get_url(self):
    return reverse("product_detail", args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])
def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name
def averageReview(self):
    reviews = ReviewRating.objects.filter(product=self, status=True).aggregate(
        average=Avg("rating")
    )
    avg = 0
    if reviews["average"] is not None:
        avg = float(reviews["average"])
    return avg
def countReview(self):
    reviews = ReviewRating.objects.filter(product=self, status=True).aggregate(
        count=Count("id")
    )
    count = 0
    if reviews["count"] is not None:
        count = int(reviews["count"])
    return count


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user}-{self.product}-{self.value}"
```

Store --> urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.store, name='store'),
path('category/<slug:category_slug>/',
     views.store, name='products_by_category'),
path('category/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/',
     views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
path('submit_review/<int:product_id>/',
     views.submit_review, name='submit_review'),
path('liked/', views.like_unlike_product, name='like_unlike_product'),]
```

Store --> views.py:

```
def like_unlike_product(request):
url = request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER")

user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

    if user_profile in product_obj.liked.all():
        product_obj.liked.remove(user_profile)
    else:
        product_obj.liked.add(user_profile)

    like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user_profile, product_id=product_id)

    if not created:
        if like.value == 'Like':
            like.value = 'Unlike'
        else:
            like.value = 'Like'
    else:
        like.value = 'Like'

        product_obj.save()
        like.save()

return redirect(url)
```

Account --> models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='userprofile')
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name

def full_address(self):
    return f'{self.address_line_1} {self.address_line_2}'

## LIKE MODEL USER ##
def get_likes_given_no(self):
    likes = self.like_set.all()
    total_liked = 0
    for item in likes:
        if item.value == 'Like':
            total_liked += 1
    return total_liked

def get_likes_recieved_no(self):
    products = self.products.all()
    total_liked = 0
    for item in products:
        total_liked += item.liked.all().count()
    return total_liked
```

mi html (product_detali.html):

```
<!-- TESTING LIKE FUNCTIONALITY FORM -->
      {% for obj in qs %}
      <form
        action="{% url 'like_unlike_product' %}"
        method="POST"
        class="like-form"
        id="{{obj.id}}"
      >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{obj.id}}" />

        <button type="submit" class="ui button like-btn{{obj.id}}">
          {% if user_profile not in obj.liked.all %}
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like! {% else %}
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>Unlike {% endif %}
        </button>

        
        <button class="btn btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like!
        </button>
       

        <div class="ui grid">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="like-count{{obj.id}}">{{obj.num_likes}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="column">Likes</div>
        </div>
      </form>
      {% endfor %}
```

SIMPLEMENTE QUIERO UN BOTON EN DONDE SE CUENTEN LOS LIKES DE CADA PRODUCTO Y TAMBIEN PUEDA DARLE UNLIKE. AYUDA POR FAVOR !!

Comment: Por favor, comparte el views.py íntegro porque ahí no sale el contexto que le estás pasando al template, por lo que no sabemos de dónde viene la variable qs.

Comment: Amigo, publique el views.py en la misma pregunta. Puse todo el codigo involucrado en el Like/Unlike button.